# Should I use "is" or "are" in this sentence

Tags: grammar

Could anyone please tell me which one of these sentences is correct?

- If you are thinking about it, chances are that so **is** many others!
- If you are thinking about it, chances are that so **are** many others!

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is definitely the correct one. The subject "many others" is plural, so it requires the plural inflection of the verb "to be," which is "are."

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking about it, chances are that so are many others!"

That's the correct answer. you are using 'many others', which is plural, so you must use 'are' instead of 'is'

Comment: This answer could be improved by citing a reliable source.